# Can AudioRecord API loose any audio frames if the data from it is not getting read but it is continuously recording?

Tags: android, audio, latency, audiorecord

This question is very important for me as I want to make my audio frames received from the `AudioRecord` API independent of the absolute time. So, basically the question is let's say I have called `AudioRecord.startRecording()`. After I do this, I start a thread (call it **Thread1**) that starts reading the audio frames from the `AudioRecorder` instance using `AudioRecord.read(...)`. While my application is running, let's say my **Thread1** gets stalled for 500 milliseconds. When the **Thread1** resumes, would I loose some audio data or the **AudioRecord** maintains a buffer to handle this (which I have a big nudge that it does)?

1. If yes, what is the size of the buffer that the `AudioRecord` maintains?
2. Is it defined in terms of the frame size for the `AudioRecord` for the device or some absolute time duration?
3. Also, how much latency can I expect from the time I call `AudioRecord.startRecording()` till when it actually starts recording the data?

I know that I have asked a lot of questions and I will be really grateful if someone could actually answer these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only buffer that `AudioRecord` uses to keep data before user consumes it is a buffer created during initialization. You can set its size via [`bufferSizeInBytes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#AudioRecord(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). If user doesn't read PCM for a while - data will be lost and replaced with new ones. So to ensure that you don't lose it - specify reasonably large buffer size. Calculation is pretty simple:

```
bufSz = samplingFreqHz * sampleSize * channelNum * bufCapacitySec;
```

E.g. to hold 5 sec of stereo 16-bit PCM sampled at 44100Hz you need 44100 * 2 * 2 * 5 = 882000 bytes. So just decide how long your reader thread sleeps and provide sufficient buffer size to `AudioRecord` to accumulate all data during that sleep.

To top it off

> If yes, what is the size of the buffer that the AudioRecord maintains?

It is your responsibility to pass proper size to constructor call.

> Is it defined in terms of the frame size for the AudioRecord for the
>   device or some absolute time duration?

It is just number of bytes, you should calculate proper size by yourself

> Also, how much latency can I expect from the time I call
>   `AudioRecord.startRecording()` till when it actually starts recording
>   the data?

There is no perfect answer. It depends on actual device and OS version. Audio recording is implemented as dedicated process and your commands and recorded data go through IPC that in general has unpredictable delays. There is a [nice articles](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/latency.html) about audio latency in Android (they are mostly about playback but I guess it may be interpolated to recording too).

Comment: How do I know the frame size at which the `AudioRecord` writes into the buffer? Is it equal to what we get from `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(...)`?

Comment: @Swapnil I guess [`AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/jb-release/media/libmedia/AudioSystem.cpp#337) is what are you talking about. It is not the same as `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize()` but they correlate somehow.